# PHP: Detect password parameter in string and replace with default text

Tags: php

I have an api logging system which records logins but I do not want to store passwords in the logs.

This is an example of a request string to the log:

NOTE: the string will not be exactly the same and will contain parameters in different order, so I am thinking maybe someREGEX can handle this?

```
api.my.geatapim/live/?action=login_user&username=joe@bloggs.com&password=PassWord&session_length=10080
```

What I need to do, is:

1. Detect if the parameter "password=" is in the string
2. If its in the string replace the password part with OBFUSCATED so result will be:

api.my.geatapim/live/?action=login_user&username=joe@bloggs.com&password=OBFUSCATED&session_length=10080

I have tried this but does not work:  `$request_string = preg_replace("/password=\d+/", "password=OBFUSCATED", $request_string);`

Comment: instead of \d+ use \w+ . \d is for digits.

Comment: Why are you not using php global $_GET[] variable to check that the 'password' is in it's index or not, and replace there itself before saving to DB?

Or if u want to do with preg_replace() itself, use \w+ instead of \d+

Comment: Why does an API use GET to transport credentials in the first place? Should be POST. And HTTPS.

Comment: although your question is quite easy to solve, it has nothing to do with your actual problem. you simply should *never* transfer password data via `$_GET` - it's one of the big *no no*-s of handling credentials.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann If they pass it via HTTPS, then there shouldn't be any problems, as stated above by CBroe. However, there's no difference if GET or POST... HTTPS is safe for either method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you never know what happens on the way and which element logs what. in short, it's just plain bad to transmit data that shouldn't be in any logs as $_GET, and transmitting it as $_POST is not exactly a hard thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it works

```
<?php

$request_string = "api.my.geatapim/live/?action=login_user&username=joe@bloggs.com&password=PassWord&session_length=10080";
echo $request_string = preg_replace("/password=\w+/", "password=OBFUSCATED", $request_string);
?>
```

Output : api.my.geatapim/live/?action=login_user&username=joe@bloggs.com&password=OBFUSCATED&session_length=10080

Comment: You sir are a true gentleman. That worked first time. I will be accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Maybe worth replacing `\w+` with `[^&]` - who knows what characters are in the password string?

Answer (score 1):

#### The Expression

`\d+` is for digits (`[0-9]`). You'll want to include more character sets for the password, considering the one you provided is using `[A-Za-z]`.

```
$request_string = preg_replace("/password=\w+/", "password=OBFUSCATED", $request_string);
```

Though, considering a typical password will have a bigger character set than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, taking into account special characters (but since it's in a URL, it'll possibly be `urlencoded()`'d. For example, `P&ssW0rd!` will become `P%26ssW0rd!`.)

```
$request_string = preg_replace("/password=[^&]+/", "password=OBFUSCATED", $request_string);
```

#### "I do not want to store passwords in the logs."

This logic won't modify what is put into your Apache/Nginx/Whatever `access_log` (unless you write these logs to `/dev/null` or another void place). You can also not write the passwords in the logs if you change it from a `HTTP GET` to a `HTTP POST` (or `HTTP PUT`) and have the credentials in the body, **or**, use [HTTP Authentication headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

> Although your question is quite easy to solve, it has nothing to do with your actual problem. you simply should never transfer password data via `$_GET` - it's one of the big no no-s of handling credentials. — [Franz Gleichmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5309228/franz-gleichmann)

Comment: hey - i'm quoted in an answer! what an honor :)

Comment: So even if I use SSL its still a no-no?

Comment: Sure. SSL doesn't affect the access_log from recording the GET parameters.